# Text Style in InDesign and Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

There is something similar to Microsft Word Text Styles, in Adobe InDesign and Illustrator?

For example I choose: "Style 1", for many paragraphs, and then I can change the font of all of them at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is in both, in fact there are two:

- **Paragraph styles** for chunks of text ending with a carriage return (paragraphs, list items, headers, table cell contents, etc).
- **Character styles** for any amount of text. You can give a paragraph a paragraph style, then give snippets of text within it character styles on top of the paragraph style.

More info: [InDesign](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WS9D351498-DAAC-4be1-B4B8-2B6C72FF6CEDa.html), [Illustrator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6395a.html). There's also basic support for [character and paragraph styles in Photoshop from CS6](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/formatting-paragraphs.html).

To find options for setting them, open the `Character Style` and `Paragraph Style` windows from the Window menu (in Illustrator they're under `Window > Type` , in InDesign, under `Window > Type and Tables` ).

If you're working from Word documents with Word styles already set up, you can [place the word document and map the Word styles to existing InDesign styles](http://www.highlander.co.uk/blog/2011/09/22/secrets-of-the-word-import-filter/) for a clean import .

Use them, and use them a lot. Also note that styles can inherit from other styles: so you can update multiple *styles* at once as well as multiple blocks of text. There's also a lot of nice advanced stuff particularly in InDesign that can be done with styles, particularly with paragraph styles, such as using them to [auto-generate tables of contents](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WS49FB9AF6-38AB-42fb-B056-8DACE18DDF63a.html) and [setting formulas (grep/regex) to automatically apply styles](http://indesignsecrets.com/5-cool-things-you-can-do-with-grep-styles.php) to certain patterns of text. It's worth doing some research on.

---

There are lots of other features based on the same principle of set a style once, then update all its instances at once. There are [Table and Cell Styles for InDesign tables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSD405E887-7AAA-432c-97D0-941BA773A47Ea.html), and [Graphic Styles (Illustrator)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-61c8a.html) and [Object Styles (InDesign)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WS5CEDB81A-0011-4dc9-9DE8-AC7AD4C80076a.html) which is a similar idea for saving fill, stroke effects and other such effects for graphic images / frames. There are also [Illustrator Symbols](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/16/an-in-depth-study-of-symbols-in-illustrator-cs5/) which are whole graphics where each instance can be edited as one.

Comment: Just a note. The hierarchical dependency of paragraph and character styles work differently between Indesign and Illustrator. In Indesign Character Styles take precedence. In Illustrator, Paragraph Styles take precedence. This can be horribly confusing at times until you realize it.

Answer (score 0):

In illustrator CS5 (under MacOSX) you can go to the menu tab Help and do a search on "Paragraph Styles" ... open it and edit as you wish.

read this for further insight: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6395a.html